# PL-SQL Conditional Block

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting error while inserting if block statement i.e.,say if B column is NULL, i need to ignore the particular row as some data is been expected & toprocess the next other record

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Sample(
A       IN DATE,
B       IN VARCHAR2,
C       IN NUMBER,
D       IN NUMBER)
IS
A1      DATE;
B1      VARCHAR2(10);
C1      NUMBER(28,12);
D1      NUMBER(28,12);

BEGIN
A1      := A;
B1      := B;
C1      := C;
D1      := D;
INSERT
INTO Sample1 VALUES
(
  A1,
  B1,
  C1,
  D1
);
END;
```

Comment: You don't need to assign A to A1, etc. Just use A. Also look at exception handling in PL/SQL, with the WHEN clause.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you please tell how to use exception handling in this case?

Comment: @Ragav try it, and post code if it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

> say if B column is NULL, i need to ignore the particular row as some
>   data is been expected & toprocess the next other record

You can use the below way. Check if `B` is not null then only insert record.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE (
    a   IN   DATE
    ,b  IN   VARCHAR2
    ,c  IN   NUMBER
    ,d  IN   NUMBER
    )
    IS

  abc EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(abc,-20001);

BEGIN
    IF b IS NOT NULL
    THEN
    INSERT INTO sample1
         VALUES (a
                ,b
                ,c
                ,d
                );
    ELSE
     Raise abc;
    END IF;
    commit;

   Exception
       ---If you want to show some user defined error you can raise here. 
       WHEN abc then 
        dbms_output.put_line('Ora:'||sqlcode||', B is Null.');

      When others then
      dbms_output.put_line('Error');           

  END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment xing..Could u plz let me know, how to fail a procedure if at all 'B' had null value?

Comment: Surely the OP only wants to ignore the case where `b` is null, so the unconditional `when others then dbms_output` is excessive. Also the `sqlcode` doesn't help here as it will just reflect the user-defined exception you raised a couple of lines earlier. Plus I feel we should be encouraging him to use formatting...

Comment: @WilliamRobertson. If you read all the comments you will find that OP first question was how to use exception handling to that I answered showing `when other` and later he asked for handling b as null to that the anwer was given by `raising a exception`. I would say you must put your suggestion of formatting under comment section of OP question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to "ignore the particular row" do you mean any call to the procedure where `b` is null? If so, just check it with an `if` condition:

```
create or replace procedure demo
    ( a in date
    , b in varchar2
    , c in number
    , d in number )
as
begin
    if b is null then
        your_logging_package.msg('Ignored insert request for a='||a||', b=null, c='||c||', d='||d);
    else
        insert into sample1 (col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d)
        values (a, b, c, d);
    end if;    
end demo;
```

Or else (since exception handling was mentioned) you could attempt the insert regardless and then handle the exception if it fails:

```
create or replace procedure demo
    ( a in date
    , b in varchar2
    , c in number
    , d in number )
as
    mandatory_value_missing exception;
    pragma exception_init(mandatory_value_missing, -1400);
begin
    insert into sample1 (col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d)
    values (a, b, c, d);
exception
    when mandatory_value_missing then
        if sqlerrm like '%"SAMPLE1"."COL_B"%' then
            your_logging_package.msg('Ignored insert request for a='||a||', b='||b||', c='||c||', d='||d);
        end if;    
end demo;
```

However,

1. this is probably over-complicated if you already know you want to skip rows where `b` is null,
   and
2. you have to check the text of the error message to make sure it only applies to column B, if that is your business rule, so this is getting a bit messy. (Bear in mind the error message may not be in English, depending on the language settings of the caller.)

Comment: The `ORA` range defined for `pragma exception_init` is between -20000 .. -20999 . See here. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#BABGIIBI

Comment: @XING, you might be thinking of `raise_application_error`. In my example, I needed to associate my custom `mandatory_value_missing` exception with `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ...`, hence -1400.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use simpler insert clause(Yo can even use only insert instead of calling a procedure):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SAMPLE ( --I Changed from procedure to function to manage exceptions and it is useful if you want to monitor the job
                                   A   IN DATE,
                                   B   IN VARCHAR2,
                                   C   IN NUMBER,
                                   D   IN NUMBER
                                  )
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO AAA
      SELECT A, B, C, D
        FROM DUAL
       WHERE B IS NOT NULL;

   RETURN SQL%ROWCOUNT;--1 is for OK and 0 is when b is NULL
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS --it is only if you have problems in destination table(space, constraints & etc.)
   THEN
      RETURN -1;
END;
```